# CameraX Recorder.Builder Implementation

Tags: java, android, android-camerax

I'm trying to create a feature where a user can record videos. But I keep getting multiple errors. I don't understand the documentation. The error is not one specific thing. Just my implementation and logic are flawed. Any ideas on how to correctly do this? Any help would be much appreciated. I've been stuck here for days.

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
private void startRecording(File videoFile) {
    this.videoFile = videoFile;

    Recorder.Builder recorderBuilder = new Recorder.Builder()
            .setExecutor(executor);

    // Create a VideoOutput using the PreviewView
    VideoOutput videoOutput = new VideoOutput(viewFinder.getSurfaceProvider().getSurface()) {
    };

    VideoCapture videoCapture = new VideoCapture.Builder()
            .setOutputFile(videoFile)
            .setTargetRotation(viewFinder.getDisplay().getRotation())
            .build();

    videoCapture.startRecording(videoOutput, executor, videoRecordEvent -> {
        // Handle video recording events
        if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Start) {
            // Recording started
            runOnUiThread(() -> {
                // Update UI if needed
            });
        } else if (videoRecordEvent instanceof VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) {
            // Recording finished or encountered an error
            VideoRecordEvent.Finalize finalizeEvent = (VideoRecordEvent.Finalize) videoRecordEvent;
            if (finalizeEvent.getError() != null) {
                // Error occurred
            }
        }
    });

    // Post a delayed message to stop video after 60 seconds
    videoStopHandler.postDelayed(videoStopRunnable, 60000);
}




private void stopRecording() {
    videoRecorder.stop();
    // Remove the callback from the handler
    videoStopHandler.removeCallbacks(videoStopRunnable);
    isRecording = false;
}

private void startCamera() {
    executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
    ProcessCameraProvider cameraProvider;
    try {
        cameraProvider = ProcessCameraProvider.getInstance(this);
        cameraProvider.addListener(() -> {
            try {
                bindPreview(cameraProvider.get());
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // Handle any errors
            }
        }, ContextCompat.getMainExecutor(this));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // Handle any errors
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see VideoCapture use case binding. Did you maybe forget it? It should be something like this: (Sorry it is in Kotlin)

```
val recorder = Recorder.Builder()
.setExecutor(cameraExecutor).setQualitySelector(qualitySelector)
.build()
val videoCapture = VideoCapture.withOutput(recorder)

try {
    // Bind use cases to camera
    cameraProvider.bindToLifecycle(
            this, CameraSelector.DEFAULT_BACK_CAMERA, preview, videoCapture)
} catch(exc: Exception) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Use case binding failed", exc)
}
```

If you don't bind it, it would not work. For more reference check here:
https://developer.android.com/training/camerax/video-capture#using-videocapture-api